# Error when trying to work on Vue custom select box dropdown?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on custom select dropdown, Where I have two dropdowns but  one dropdown is working fine, but when selecting the second dropdown, I am unable to select the data.

In the js file I can see the data, But for the second dropdown how to write the data and pass it to the second dropdown.

```js
    const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
        name: 'aselect',
        data: {
            value: 'Select a Fruit',
            list: ["Orange","Apple","Kiwi", "Lemon", "Pineapple"],
      visible: false,
      value2: 'Select a Fruit',
            list2: ["Orange","Apple","Kiwi", "Lemon", "Pineapple"],
      visible2: false
        },
        methods: {
            toggle() {
                this.visible = !this.visible;
            },
            select(option) {
                this.value = option;
            },
        toggle2() {
                this.visible2 = !this.visible2;
            },
            select(option) {
                this.value2 = option;
            }
        }
    })
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mogra|Roboto');
body {
  background: STEELBLUE;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

h1 {
  color: #f9f9f9;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Mogra";
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-shadow: 3px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.aselect {
        width: 280px;
    margin: 20px auto;
        .selector {
            border: 1px solid gainsboro;
            background: #F8F8F8;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            .arrow {
                position: absolute;
                right: 10px;
                top: 40%;
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border-left: 7px solid transparent;
                border-right: 7px solid transparent;
                border-top: 10px solid #888;
                transform: rotateZ(0deg) translateY(0px);
                transition-duration: 0.3s;
                transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.59,1.39,.37,1.01);
            }
            .expanded {
                transform: rotateZ(180deg) translateY(2px);
            }
            .label {
                display: block;
                padding: 12px;
                font-size: 16px;
                color: #888;
            }
        }
        ul {
            width: 100%;
            list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: 1px solid gainsboro;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
      background: #fff;
        }
        li {
            padding: 12px;
            color: #666;
            &:hover {
                color: white;
                background: seagreen;
            }
        }
        .current {
            background: #eaeaea;
        }
        .hidden {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        .visible {
            visibility: visible;
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">  
<div class="aselect" :data-value="value" :data-list="list">
        <div class="selector" @click="toggle()">
            <div class="label">
                    <span>{{ value }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="arrow" :class="{ expanded : visible }"></div>
            <div :class="{ hidden : !visible, visible }">
                <ul>
                    <li :class="{ current : item === value }" v-for="item in list" @click="select(item)">{{ item }}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">  
<div class="aselect" :data-value="value2" :data-list="list2">
        <div class="selector" @click="toggle2()">
            <div class="label">
                    <span>{{ value }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="arrow" :class="{ expanded : visible2 }"></div>
            <div :class="{ hidden : !visible2, visible2 }">
                <ul>
                    <li :class="{ current : item === value }" v-for="item in list" @click="select(item)">{{ item }}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working codepen https://codepen.io/dieser/pen/ZyOKmB

Error when trying to duplicate dropdown Codepen link https://codepen.io/santoshch/pen/QWpbPZr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few bugs in your [codepen](https://codepen.io/santoshch/pen/QWpbPZr)

#### 1. Code wasn't in #app

When mounting a vue app, you could see `el: '#app'` in main.js.

So simply put your code inside of `<div id="app>`

#### 2. Repeated methods `select()`

I can see you are trying to duplicate a method `select()` from the working example. Remember to rename the method to avoid duplicated function name.

### TL;DR

Here is the working [codepen](https://codepen.io/blackcityhenry/pen/YzZyzed)

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the select into a component for code reusability and isolation. You can pass different data to the select components using  `props`

Creating methods like `select2()` is a bad idea.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/santoshch/pen/QWpbPZr)

```js
Vue.component('my-select', {
  template: `<div class="aselect" :data-value="value" :data-list="list">
    <div class="selector" @click="toggle()">
      <div class="label">
        <span>{{ value }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="arrow" :class="{ expanded : visible }"></div>
      <div :class="{ hidden : !visible, visible }">
        <ul>
          <li :class="{ current : item === value }" v-for="item in list" @click="select(item)">{{ item }}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`,
  props: ['list'],
  data: () => ({
    value: 'Select a Fruit',
    visible: false,
  }),
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.visible = !this.visible;
    },
    select(option) {
      this.value = option;
    }
  }
});
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  name: 'aselect',
  data: {
    list1: ["Orange", "Apple", "Kiwi", "Lemon", "Pineapple"],
    list2: ["Orange", "Apple", "Kiwi", "Lemon", "Pineapple"],
  }
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mogra|Roboto');
body {
  background: STEELBLUE;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

h1 {
  color: #f9f9f9;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Mogra";
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-shadow: 3px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.aselect {
  width: 280px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  .selector {
    border: 1px solid gainsboro;
    background: #F8F8F8;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    .arrow {
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      top: 40%;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 7px solid transparent;
      border-right: 7px solid transparent;
      border-top: 10px solid #888;
      transform: rotateZ(0deg) translateY(0px);
      transition-duration: 0.3s;
      transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.59, 1.39, .37, 1.01);
    }
    .expanded {
      transform: rotateZ(180deg) translateY(2px);
    }
    .label {
      display: block;
      padding: 12px;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #888;
    }
  }
  ul {
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid gainsboro;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #fff;
  }
  li {
    padding: 12px;
    color: #666;
    &:hover {
      color: white;
      background: seagreen;
    }
  }
  .current {
    background: #eaeaea;
  }
  .hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .visible {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-select :list="list1"></my-select>
  <my-select :list="list2"></my-select>
</div>
```